# Change the Artifactory Server Certificate

Tags: artifactory

I see documentation on trusting certificates for Artifactory to connect outside but I want to run artifictory with a certifiacte signed by my enterprise CA. How do I do that?

Signed certificate with microsoft enterprise CA. exported and converted to PEM, just need to know where the conf is for changing the server's certificate to use this

Answer (score 1):

JFrog Artifactory is bundled with a Tomcat server which runs the actual app. You can change the settings in the `settings.xml` to use a signed certificate (which does require a restart of Artifactory, so please be aware of that). Tomcats own [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) has great details on which steps are required